# Promise.all() вызывает указанную функцию ДО выполнения парсинга

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

```
function loot(){
    return fetch('https://loot.farm/fullprice.json', { method: "GET", mode: "no-cors", cache: "no-cache" }).then(response=>response.json());
};

function skinsjar(){
    return fetch('https://skinsjar.com/api/v3/load/bots?refresh=0&v=2', { method: "GET", mode: "no-cors", cache: "no-cache" }).then(response=>response.json());
};

function start(data){
    console.log(data);
};

Promise.all([skinsjar(), loot()]).then(results=> start(results));
```

Вот вам пример, когда-то это было расширение для хрома и работало замечательно, сейчас переделываю под сайт это и сначала дал ошибку на cors, сделал `mode: 'no-cors';`, потом пожаловался на .json(), это я убрал и увидел что start() вызывается ДО того как сайт отдаст вообще данные, хотя когда это было расширение давало как надо, после получения, код вообще не менял, что может быть не так?

Comment: Ну Вы же отдаёте обещание только для загрузки, а парсинг происходит уже после разрешения. Нужно отдавать отдельное обещание, типа: `function loot(){
    return new Promise((res, rej) => fetch('https://loot.farm/fullprice.json', { method: "GET", mode: "no-cors", cache: "no-cache" }).then(response=>response.json()).then(_ => res()));
};`.

Comment: @Other, зачем оборачивать Promise в Promise если Promise и так есть? :-)

Comment: Посмотри данный ответ: [fetch() unexpected end of input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45697474/2881286) - проблема в сайтах, которые не шлют CORS заголовки